# Julia export command fails to export all functions in module

Tags: julia

I'm having trouble accessing an exported function from a module. The code for the module is

```
module SteinDistributions

export
# Abstract types
SteinDistribution,
SteinPosterior,
# Specific distributions
SteinDiscrete,
SteinGMMPosterior,
SteinGaussian,
SteinLogisticRegressionPosterior,
SteinLogisticRegressionGaussianPrior,
SteinScaleLocationStudentT,
SteinUniform,
# Common functions operating on distributions
# CDF of a distribution
cdf,
# Get Stein factors
getC1,
getC2,
getC3,
# Lower bound on range of coordinate
supportlowerbound,
# Upper bound on range of coordinate
supportupperbound,
# Number of dimensions of target variable
numdimensions,
# get number of samples when distribution is posterior of data
numdatapoints,
# the log prior for posterior distributions
logprior,
# the likelihood [without a prior for posterior distributions]
loglikelihood,
# Log density [will include prior for posterior distributions]
logdensity,
# Gradient of the prior
gradlogprior,
# Gradient of the log density
gradlogdensity,
# Gradient of the log likelihood
gradloglikelihood,
# Random samples drawn from distribution
rand,
# random GMM samples
randgmm,
# evaluating joint and conditional probability mass functions for
# discrete distributions
jointdistribution,
condlogodds,
conddistribution

# Include abstract types first
include("SteinDistribution.jl")
include("SteinPosterior.jl")
# Include specific distributions
include("SteinDiscrete.jl")
include("SteinGMMPosterior.jl")
include("SteinGaussian.jl")
include("SteinLogisticRegressionPosterior.jl")
include("SteinLogisticRegressionGaussianPrior.jl")
include("SteinScaleLocationStudentT.jl")
include("SteinUniform.jl")
end
```

yet I encounter the following error

```
julia> using SteinDistributions: SteinUniform
ERROR: SteinUniform not defined
```

The output of whos() only lists some of the functions in the module, and I'm unsure what determines which functions are exported:

```
julia> whos(SteinDistributions)
SteinDistribution             DataType
SteinDistributions            Module
SteinPosterior                DataType
getC1                         Function
getC2                         Function
getC3                         Function
gradlogdensity                Function
gradloglikelihood             Function
logdensity                    Function
numdatapoints                 Function
rand                          Function
supportlowerbound             Function
supportupperbound             Function
```

I was hoping someone could help me with this. 
Thanks,
Dar

Comment: Without seeing your external files it's really difficult see what's going wrong. Are you sure you defined all the functions in the `.jl` files?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The start of the file SteinUniform.jl for instance contains the following code. 


`type SteinUniform <: SteinDistribution
    range::Array{Float64, 2}
    c1::Float64
    c2::Float64
    c3::Float64
end`

comparing this to your code, doesn't it seems like the export should work?

Comment: Okay, this still works okay for me. It's really hard to figure out where the problem is without a reproducible example. Maybe try to shorten your question a bit. Does it fail with just `SteinDistribution` and `SteinUniform`? If you can isolate a smaller piece of code, it'll be easier to debug.